# IF + ISNUMBER + SEARCH Formula from a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a formula that will enter specific texts from a table, when the cell had certain keywords. I've seen a formula here, but I can't seem to add more texts to it.

What should be my formula below? My formula doesn't seem to work:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("E2:E5",A1)),"F2:F5","")

Keywords = Text

- Dog Mammals Lassie = Mammals
- Mammals Cat Snowball 564 = Mammals
- Prince Snake Reptiles = Reptiles
- Peace Dove Birds = Birds

Comment: REmove the `"` around the range references.

Comment: I need to formula to search for the keywords from the cell and match it from the column of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your formula, remove the `"` around the range references. `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2:E5,A1)),F2:F5,"")` But that will get you list of the return and blanks.

You want INDEX(MATCH()):

```
=INDEX(F2:F5,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2:E5,A1)),0))
```

Depending on version it may require usage of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If you have it FILTER would be a good alternative also:

```
=@FILTER(F2:F5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2:E5,A1)))
```